# Is gaming on ubuntu possible (choice of games)

Tags: upgrade, graphics, 13.04, games

So im updating my old pc preferable for gaming. 
Are the games (mainly first person shooters) on the market able to be played on Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe have a look at wine software

Answer (score 1):

Gaming to an extent is possible on Ubuntu. Wine has a database, which includes games that have been ported perfectly and can be played on the linux system.
Additionally, towards the end of last year, steam came on to Ubuntu officially, so all of games developed by Steam can now be played by users on Ubuntu. 
To install Steam-

> Ubuntu Software Centre->Search for Steam in the top right-hand corner of the app->Install

Go to this link [wine-hq](http://appdb.winehq.org/), to check out everything that wine has to offer.

Since you're interested in fps games go to [wine-search](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true), here, under category if you choose first person shooter, you'll get the entire list.

Additionally, check out [wine top 25](http://appdb.winehq.org/votestats.php), for the top 25 games that wine has ported to Linux.

Hope this helped.